# jQuery sub-navigation alternating visibility

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidedown

I am in the process of developing a site in which some links in the primary navigation have individual sub-menus  - nothing unusual.

But, I am attempting to control the visibility of the sub-menus. When the cursor hovers over a link with a sub-menu, the sub-menu should slidedown. If the cursor goes and hovers over a different link with another sub-menu, the same effect should happen but I am trying to hide away any open sub-menus before sliding down the newly requested sub-menu.

I am using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function(){
        jQuery('div#block-system-main-menu div.content ul li.leaf').mouseover(
            function(){
                //jQuery('div.view-referenced-product-categories').slideUp();
                jQuery(this).find('div.view h3').slideDown();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

With that code, my slidedown works fine but I end up with multiple sub-menus open. If I uncomment the first line of code in the mouseover function, my slidedown effects does not work.

*To illustrate, the site is at http://hoffmann-koree.com/. The 2 links with sub-menus are **bathroom** and **stationary**.*

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or a better technique perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `slideDown()` in the callback of `slideUp()`

```
var menu = this;
jQuery('div.view-referenced-product-categories').slideUp(500, function (){
    jQuery(menu).find('div.view h3').slideDown();
});
```

this way, `slideDown()` will only be called when `slideUp()` is completed. (I put 500ms for speed as it's the default one but maybe it'll be better if you put a faster speed for hiding the menus)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried your suggestion but it did not work for me - but that's likely because I don't understand how to use it very well. Can you offer a more detailed example, please?

Comment: Well, this code is supposed to `slideUp()` every `div` that have `.view-referenced-product-categories` as a class and then, when the sliding is finished, start `slideDown()` on every `h3` elements under `div` with `.view` class that are under `this` which should be your `mouseover` element: `div#block-system-main-menu div.content ul li.leaf`. However, I think I made a mistake, `var menu = this;` should be `var menu = jquery(this)`. I don't know if it will solve your problem but you could try it.

Comment: After looking at your site, I think you also need to replace `'div.view h3'` with `'div.view div.view-content h3'`

Comment: Ye, I noticed and corrected your mistake from your original post but it does not solve the problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

why not just use mouseleave?

```
jQuery('div#block-system-main-menu div.content ul li.leaf').mouseover(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).find('div.view h3').slideDown();
    }
);
jQuery('div#block-system-main-menu div.content ul li.leaf').mouseleave(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).find('div.view h3').slideUp();
    }
);
```

I checked your source code, and if you want to add it in, just edit your hoffmannkoree.js and replace lines 4-16 with the snippet above.